# Mysql workbench create script is missing the comments of table columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im using mysql for generating table create script. Whilst creating script I have comments made against some of the columns - which would be very useful to have it in the script as comments for that column.

But Im unable to make these comment appear when I generate the script.

How to do this ? Im sure I am missing something trivial here.

Comment: Did you set the comment on the column on the right of the columns option? Because it exports the comments with any things selected.

Comment: I have lot of comments and they are appearing now ! I did restart workbench sometime ago - may be that did it. Thanks for asking - I wouldn't 've checked it soon enough :)